How to summarize the total of a calculated if statement field, in Tableau?
I have a table that contains fields date, amount and Client_ID.
I want to get the count of clients who had an avg R3M greater than same period last year, for every month.
The issue is when I get a calculated field that flags clients with R3M greater than SPLY using an if statement, I am unable to sum the results of that field. I keep getting 1 instead of getting the total count.
My calculations:
R3M: WINDOW_Avg(SUM([Amount]),-2,0)
SPLY: WINDOW_Avg(SUM([Amount]),-14,-12)
comparison: if [R3M] > [R3M - SPLY] then 1 ELSE 0 END
final count (problematic): if [comparison] = 1 then ATTR([Client_ID]) END
Any help is appreciated!

The [final count] calculation needs more than one thing to count. [final count] currently reads as: For this query, give me the count of every ID in this row that matches my requirements. This will always be 1. We want: For this query, return all the rows that match requirements THEN count them.
To do this, remove the attribute around Client ID, so from ATTR([Client_ID]), to just [Client_ID]. This will get you that list of all the client Ids that match your criteria. From here we just take the COUNT of that list. You can do so by dragging it to your worksheet and right clicking the pill convert to measure -> count
Additionally, if you are only looking for the flagged accounts you can remove the THEN 1 ELSE 0 END from your [comparison] calculations and replace it with THEN [Client_ID] END and take the COUNT of [comparison]

As your new, and FYI is to try to keep comments relevant to the question and answers going forward. That being said, did it fix the issue? If so, say thanks by accepting the answer so that others my find it if they have the same issue.

Thank you @Muff. for taking the time to answer and for the explanations!
The issue is when I remove ATTR, I receive an error msg saying "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate comparisons or results in if expression."
Same thing happens when I use:
if [R3M] > [R3M - SPLY] then [Client_ID] ELSE 0 END
Any extra leads would be appreciated!

You can do a little bit of type manipulation to get around this, probably not best practice, but I am strapped for time right now. Try if STR([comparison]) = "1" THEN [Client_ID] END

It still returns "Cannot mix aggregate and non-aggregate..." error.

See this question on SO.
